# Error creating database in SQL Server Management Studio. (Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Sqm)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I'm trying to create a new database in SSMS, but I get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Sqm, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (SqlMgmt)

Answer (score 4):

Close Management Studio.

Find the file `Microsoft.SqlServer.Sqm.dll` located in one of the following folders:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Shared\
>   
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\
>   
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\

Wherever you find it, make sure it also exists in the other two locations.

I don't *know* that this will solve your issue, so please let me know - if not I will delete this. This was just too complex to add as a comment.

Comment: I have the file in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Shared\ folder. But unfortunately I don't have the other two folder. I only have ManagementStudio, Resources and schemas folder in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn . Any idea?

Comment: should I copy it at the dir C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ ? because I dont have the \VSShell\Common7\IDE\ folder.

Comment: @Ren Sorry, I don't know. Sounds to me like you should completely uninstall, reinstall, and make sure you apply *at least* service pack 1 (if you are using SQL Express, [get it here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579)).

Answer (score 0):

It's because the exact verion 11.0.*.* was not found in the folder where 'ssms.exe' is present.

***Solution***

Goto the exact folder where 'ssms.exe' is present by going to start menu and typing ssms.exe. then right click the result and click 'open file location'.

In that location try to paste the exact 11.0.*.* version of 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Sqm'.

In my case it asked for 12.0.0.0 version and i pasted 12.0.2000.8 and it worked like a charm.!!!! cheers.!!!